# D3 Adjust Scatterplot Axes for Tiny Data Set

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 scatterplot that filters out data based on input criteria. As the data set remains large, 200+ items, having the Axes adjust to scale to the minimum and maximum range is nice. But as the data set becomes filtered down to, let's say 4 or fewer items, I only have a few points that occupy the edges of the plot, like this:
[image]

As this is responsive data visualization, having these points on the edge of the screen is not good for interaction. I can of course, create a new scale that calls when there are less than 4 values and wrap the `xScale` and `yScale` in an `if` statement. However, this doesn't seem like a very performant or elegant solution. **Without changing the scales, is there a performant way to display these points closer to the visual center of the scatterplot?**

Comment: Add some padding beyond the extent of the domains, e.g. if the points cover a range `[1,9]` make the domain `[0,10]`.

Comment: Perfect. I ended up using something like `xMax + (xMax / 3)`/`xMax - (xMax / 3)` for the domain values.

Comment: You could also just call `.nice()` on the scale.